# Cast query result as decimal in mysql

Tags: mysql, mariadb

**What I have:**

- Mariadb version : 10.3.10

I have a table `visits` that has 2 columns `userid` and `ref_url`, where `userid` is the id of the users and `ref_url` corresponds to the url from which the `userid` was referred. Empty spaces in the column `ref_url` corresponds to direct visits and are not considered.

Table: `vists`

```
-------------------------------------
|  userid |        ref_url          | 
-------------------------------------
|      1  |                         |
|      1  | https://demosite.com    | 
|      1  | https://demosite2.com   |
|      1  |                         |
|      1  | https://demosite3.com   | 
|      1  |                         |
-------------------------------------
```

**What I expect to achieve:**

I want to create a query that will count the total number of `ref_url` occurrences for a particular `userid` excluding empty spaces (in the ref_url field), limit the count within 100 and multiply the count with 0.5 and represent the result as DECIMAL on an alias column `estimated value`.

```
------------------------------------
|  userid |    estimated value     | 
------------------------------------
|      1  |       1.50             |
------------------------------------
```

**My Query:**

```
SELECT userid,
       CAST(((
              SELECT COUNT(NULLIF(TRIM(ref_url), ''))
                  FROM visits
                  LIMIT 0,100
             ) * 0.5) AS DECIMAL(12,2)) AS 'estimated value'
FROM visits

GROUP BY userid
```

The above query throws a syntax error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '2))

The query works when `DECIMAL(12,2)` is replaced by `UNSIGNED`.

The query when used with DECIMAL(12,2) outputs with Adminer but results in

> [1329] No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processed

when tried directly on Mariadb. Is there a chance of permission issues?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, at least not with what I am trying locally.

Comment: What is your current DB Version? btw. could you try with float(12,2) ?

Comment: This query runs fine with my MariaDB version 10.0.36-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.16.04.1. Which one do you use?

Comment: it's working fine for me : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6650d9e/1

Comment: @Christian Felix  I tried float, same result. Surprisingly, query outputs with adminer, but gives no data fetched error when directly executed on Mariadb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LIMIT` occurs *after* the data is gathered.  Your subquery gathers only one row, so the `LIMIT` is irrelevant.  However, since you are using MariaDB (not MySQL), you can say

```
LIMIT ROWS EXAMINED 100
```

(Caveat:  I have not tested this.)

Ref:  https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/limit-rows-examined/ -- since MariaDB 5.5.21

As for `DECIMAL` -- Instead of `CAST(expression AS DECIMAL(10,2))`, use

```
FORMAT(expression, 2)
```

Comment: FORMAT nailed it!! So, would like to know why FORMAT did it, while CAST didn't? Is it because of a nested query ? One more thing, I think FORMAT returns the result as string value and not numeric, is that correct?

Comment: @mesumosu - I have not figured out why it went wrong.  `FORMAT`, as the name implies, is a formatting function, hence returns a string.  (It also adds 'thousands separators' in big numbers.)

Comment: @mesumosu - `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'div_precision_increment';` [_Ref_](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html)